# log problem $x^y = e^{....}$

Tags: calculus, functions

$$f(y)=x^y=e^{y\log (x)}$$
can anyone help me why this is equal? which rules do it use?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar3oh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1sm0.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What do you know about logarithms ?

Comment: What is your *definition* of $x^y$ for real numbers $x, y$?

Comment: x>0, no define of y

Answer (score 1):

$$x^y=(e^{\log(x)})^y=e^{\log(x)y}$$ because $$(a^b)^c=a^{bc}.$$

Comment: Correction: $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ provided $a>0$.  Fortunately, $e>0$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Correction: $a>0$ makes no sense for the complex numbers. Fortunately, $e$ is a positive real.

Answer (score 0):

$f(y)= x^y $  implies
$$\log f(y)=y \log x$$   implies
$$f(y)= \exp(y \log x)$$

Comment: IMO, this says nothing because the first "implies" is just a restatement of the initial claim by taking the logarithm, but with no justification.

Answer (score 0):

It uses

- $z=e^{\log_e(z)}$ for $z \gt 0$
- $\log(x^y)=y \log(x)$ for $x \gt 0$

so

- $x^y =e^{\log_e(x^y)} =e^{y\log_e(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

$e^{\log (x)} = x.\ $ Also, for $a>0, \ (a^b)^c = a^{bc}.\ $ Therefore $\ e^{y\log (x)} = (e^{\log (x)})^y = x^y$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You mainly just use the power rule and rearrange the log, shown in my image:

Comment: Your third line is plain wrong. Please spare us that.

Comment: You mean the second line is plain wrong.

Comment: How is it wrong

Comment: The second line should be $ \log (f(y)) = y\log(x) \log ({e}) $, not $(\log(e))^{y \log (x)}$. And by the way we should all be using $ln$, not $log$.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the equality you wrote is **not always true**. For example, if $x=-1$, then the right side of the equality is **undefined**.

---

However, I assume that you are missing one assumption in your question, and that is that $x>0$. In this case:

From the basic properties of logarithmic functions we know that for all $a>0$, we have $e^{\ln (a)} = a$, we can see (by setting $a=x^y$) that $$x^y=e^{\ln\left(x^y\right)}$$

Also, from the basic properties of logarithmic functions, we know that $$\ln\left(x^y\right)=y\cdot \ln x.$$

Now just put these two equalities together.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why they thought my answer was so bad it needed to be downvoted?